# How to make a search that search through an html file in a static website, regardless any page search bar is located

Tags: javascript, html

I am using below function to search in articles.html - My search bar is in the home page (index.html).

```
 <div id="tfheader">
      <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="articles.html">
                <input type="text" class="tftextinput" id="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120">
                <input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
      </form>
      <div class="tfclear"></div>
 </div>

<script>
    var a = document.getElementById('tfnewsearch');
    a.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var b = document.getElementById('tftextinput').value;
           window.location.href = 'articles.html'+b;

    });

</script>
```

My requirement is when i type some character in search bar and hit enter. It will redirect me to article.html and search through whole content of article.html

Thanks for the help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Gomac Knowledgebase</title>
    <!-- LOADING STYLESHEETS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid featured-area-white-border">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="login-box border-right-1">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-key"></i> Login</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-box border-left-1 border-right-1">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- LOGO -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END LOGO-->
    <!-- TOP NAVIGATION -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="topnav">
                    <li></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>  Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="knowledge-base.html"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Knowledge Base</a></li>
                    <li><a href="articles.html"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="faq.html"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i> FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="icon">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION -->
    <!-- SEARCH FIELD AREA -->
    <div class="searchfield bg-hed-six">
        <div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
            <div class="row text-center margin-bottom-20">
                <h1 class="white"> Knowledge Base</h1>
                <span class="nested"> Learn to use gomac </span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row search-row">
                <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="What do you need help with?">
                <button class="buttonsearch btn btn-info btn-lg">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SEARCH FIELD AREA -->
    <!-- MAIN SECTION -->
    <div class="container featured-area-default padding-30">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- ARTICLE OVERVIEW SECTION -->
            <div class="col-md-8 padding-20">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- BREADCRUMBS -->
                    <div class="breadcrumb-container">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="active">All Articles</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END BREADCRUMBS -->
                    <!-- ARTICLES -->
                    <div class="fb-heading">
                        All Articles
                    </div>
                    <hr class="style-three">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="article-heading-abb">
                            <a href="single-article.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> How to change account password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <div class="art-date"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 20 May, 2016 </a></div>
                            <div class="art-category"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Account Settings </a></div>
                            <div class="art-comments"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 4 Comments </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-content">
                            <p class="block-with-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet finibus dui. Fusce ac nulla nec ex ornare vehicula non nec mi. Cras eget nisi sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec viverra
                                faucibus magna sed interdum. Phasellus ultrices sagittis molestie. Sed sit amet nisl id risus egestas semper. In porta, arcu eu dignissim vestibulum, sapien justo imperdiet enim, sed facilisis quam justo in neque. Aliquam
                                fermentum arcu eget hendrerit efficitur.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-read-more">
                            <a href="single-article.html" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Read more...</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="article-heading-abb">
                            <a href="single-article.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> How to change currency in gomac?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <div class="art-date"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 20 May, 2016 </a></div>
                            <div class="art-category"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Admin Panel </a></div>
                            <div class="art-comments"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 10 Comments </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-content">
                            <p class="block-with-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet finibus dui. Fusce ac nulla nec ex ornare vehicula non nec mi. Cras eget nisi sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec viverra
                                faucibus magna sed interdum. Phasellus ultrices sagittis molestie. Sed sit amet nisl id risus egestas semper. In porta, arcu eu dignissim vestibulum, sapien justo imperdiet enim, sed facilisis quam justo in neque. Aliquam
                                fermentum arcu eget hendrerit efficitur.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-read-more">
                            <a href="single-article.html" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Read more...</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="article-heading-abb">
                            <a href="single-article.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> How to edit order details?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <div class="art-date"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 20 May, 2016 </a></div>
                            <div class="art-category"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Orders </a></div>
                            <div class="art-comments"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 0 Comments </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-content">
                            <p class="block-with-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet finibus dui. Fusce ac nulla nec ex ornare vehicula non nec mi. Cras eget nisi sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec viverra
                                faucibus magna sed interdum. Phasellus ultrices sagittis molestie. Sed sit amet nisl id risus egestas semper. In porta, arcu eu dignissim vestibulum, sapien justo imperdiet enim, sed facilisis quam justo in neque. Aliquam
                                fermentum arcu eget hendrerit efficitur.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-read-more">
                            <a href="single-article.html" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Read more...</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="article-heading-abb">
                            <a href="single-article.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> How to print stock barcode?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <div class="art-date"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 20 May, 2016 </a></div>
                            <div class="art-category"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Stocks </a></div>
                            <div class="art-comments"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 12 Comments </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-content">
                            <p class="block-with-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet finibus dui. Fusce ac nulla nec ex ornare vehicula non nec mi. Cras eget nisi sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec viverra
                                faucibus magna sed interdum. Phasellus ultrices sagittis molestie. Sed sit amet nisl id risus egestas semper. In porta, arcu eu dignissim vestibulum, sapien justo imperdiet enim, sed facilisis quam justo in neque. Aliquam
                                fermentum arcu eget hendrerit efficitur.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-read-more">
                            <a href="single-article.html" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Read more...</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="article-heading-abb">
                            <a href="single-article.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> How to generate barcode?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-info">
                            <div class="art-date"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 20 May, 2016 </a></div>
                            <div class="art-category"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Stocks </a></div>
                            <div class="art-comments"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 7 Comments </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-content">
                            <p class="block-with-text">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet finibus dui. Fusce ac nulla nec ex ornare vehicula non nec mi. Cras eget nisi sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec viverra
                                faucibus magna sed interdum. Phasellus ultrices sagittis molestie. Sed sit amet nisl id risus egestas semper. In porta, arcu eu dignissim vestibulum, sapien justo imperdiet enim, sed facilisis quam justo in neque. Aliquam
                                fermentum arcu eget hendrerit efficitur.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article-read-more">
                            <a href="single-article.html" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Read more...</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END ARTICLES -->

                    <!-- PAGINATION -->
                    <nav class="text-center">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="disabled">
                                <a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Previous</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li class="enabled"><a href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li class="enabled"><a href="#">3 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li class="enabled">
                                <a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- END PAGINATION -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END ARTICLES OVERVIEW SECTION-->
            <!-- SIDEBAR STUFF -->
            <div class="col-md-4 padding-20">
                <div class="row margin-bottom-30">
                    <div class="col-md-12 ">
                        <div class="support-container">
                            <h2 class="support-heading">Need more Support?</h2> If you cannot find an answer in the knowledgebase, you can <a href="#">contact us</a> for further help.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row margin-top-20">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="fb-heading-small">
                            Popular Articles
                        </div>
                        <hr class="style-three">
                        <div class="fat-content-small padding-left-10">
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> How to change account password?</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> How to edit order details?</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Add new user</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Change customer details</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Lookup existing customer in order form</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row margin-top-20">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="fb-heading-small">
                            Latest Articles
                        </div>
                        <hr class="style-three">
                        <div class="fat-content-small padding-left-10">
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> How to change username?</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> How to change currency in gomac?</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> How to edit order details?</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> How to print stock barcode?</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> How to generate barcode?</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- POPULAR TAGS (SHOW MAX 20 TAGS) -->
                <div class="row margin-top-20">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="fb-heading-small">
                            Popular Tags
                        </div>
                        <hr class="style-three">
                        <div class="fat-content-tags padding-left-10">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">password</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">settings</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">sign up</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">currency</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">payment</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">user</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">database</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">storage</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">export</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">email</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">import</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">campaign</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">edit</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">orders</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">help</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">billing</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">user</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">configure</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-o btn-sm">customer</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END POPULAR TAGS (SHOW MAX 20 TAGS) -->
            </div>
            <!-- END SIDEBAR STUFF -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN SECTION -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div class="container-fluid footer marg30">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- FOOTER COLUMN ONE -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 margin-top-20">
                <div class="panel-transparent">
                    <div class="footer-heading">How it works</div>
                    <div class="footer-body">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END FOOTER COLUMN ONE -->
            <!-- FOOTER COLUMN TWO -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 margin-top-20">
                <div class="panel-transparent">
                    <div class="footer-heading">Categories</div>
                    <div class="footer-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href="single-category.html">General</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-category.html">Getting Started</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-category.html">Account Support</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-category.html">Guides</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-category.html">Payment &amp; Billing</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-category.html">Misc</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END FOOTER COLUMN TWO -->
            <!-- FOOTER COLUMN THREE -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 margin-top-20">
                <div class="panel-transparent">
                    <div class="footer-heading">Popular Articles</div>
                    <div class="footer-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li> <a href="single-article.html">How to change account password</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-article.html">How to edit order details</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-article.html">Add new user</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-article.html">Change customer details</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-article.html">Lookup existing customer in order form</a> </li>
                            <li> <a href="single-article.html">How do I reset my password</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END FOOTER COLUMN THREE -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->

    <!-- COPYRIGHT INFO -->
    <div class="container-fluid footer-copyright marg30">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pull-left">
                Copyright © 2016 Sunny Gohil</a>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> &nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> &nbsp;
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END COPYRIGHT INFO -->

    <!-- LOADING MAIN JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/VPenkov/okayNav/master/app/js/jquery.okayNav.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Above is the html for articles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - Parse the string from url an then search it in the document.

```
var a = document.getElementById('tfnewsearch');
if(a){
    a.addEventListener('submit',function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var b = document.getElementById('tftextinput').value;
           window.location.href = 'articles.html?'+b;
    });
}
  // var queryString = url.substring( url.indexOf('?') + 1 );
  var queryString = window.location.search;
queryString = queryString.substring(1);

function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var para, filter, ul, li, anchor;

    para = document.getElementById('block-with-text');

    filter = queryString.toUpperCase();
    anchor = document.getElementById("anchor");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];


        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else if (p.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
myFunction();
```